# Mixins and includes in Slim Template Engine

Tags: haml, pug, template-engine, slim-lang

I'm new to Slim, and I really enjoy it, but I was wondering does it support mixins or variables or includes like Jade for example?

In Jade, you just have to do:

```
include ./includes/head.jade
```

and you can easily include other Jade files in it.

It works on similar way for mixins:

```
  //- Declaration
    mixin list
      ul
        li foo
        li bar
        li baz
    //- Use
    +list
    +list
```

I was just wondering is there a simple way in Slim to do so, or should I just switch to Jade?

Answer (score 0):

As of this posting, Slim does not directly support mixins, includes, or extends.

However, Slim is able to call Ruby, so it would at least be possible to implement these features in Ruby and to call them from Slim.

These features were the reason we just selected Jade for our own use. Jade syntax is unnecessarily picky but still better than working directly with HTML. Hopefully at some point we will have something more on par with SASS for HTML.